# Compare dataframes based on row values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

What is the best way to compare two datasets (.csv files) using Pandas where there is no 1:1 cardinality between the data?

For example: Here's a sample from dataset one -

```
#### Row Item Color Price
01 Shirt Red $30
02 Hat Blue $10
```

And a sample from dataframe two -

```
#### Row Item Color Price
01 Trouser Black $20
02 Bag Yellow $ 30
03 Hat Blue $10
04 Shirt Red $30
```

So if I wanted to **compare all rows in both datasets where there is a Shirt row**.

what is the best way to do it?

I'm using Pandas/Python3.7

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be -
 
Shirt Red $30 matching with Shirt Red $30 from both dataframes and Hat Blue $10 matching with Hat Blue $10 from both dataframes. So basically, if there is a row values called Shirt in both dataframes, then all columns should be compared for those rows.

Answer (score 1):

check this example:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1':['abc','abc','iop','iop'],'c2':['xyz','mno','yut','trg'],'c3':[0,0,0,0]})

    c1  c2  c3
0   abc xyz 0
1   abc mno 0
2   iop yut 0
3   iop trg 0


DF2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1':['iop','abc','bhj','iop','xdf'],'c2':['yut','mno','uio','yut','edc']})
    c1  c2
0   iop yut
1   abc mno
2   bhj uio
3   iop yut
4   xdf edc
match = pd.merge(DF1,DF2,on=['c1','c2'],how='inner')
print(match)

    c1  c2  c3
0   abc mno 0
1   iop yut 0
2   iop yut 0
```

So by using `pd.merge` you can get the matching rows

Comment: So I don't know where the row value Shirt is present in both datasets. Can I still use inner merge?

Comment: That's awesome! I'm going to try this and update. Using multiple columns as a list also helps, because I have a set of 'key' columns that I want to compare if the row element is found to be the same. :)

Comment: sure, you can check the docs so as to handle the suffixes given by merge function. you can also drop them if unwanted :)

Comment: @GreedyCoder : if any of the answers helped, please dont forget to accept one of the answers so people can refer this question later and find their solution. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use pandas `merge` like this:

```
pd.merge(df1[df1.Item == 'Shirt'], df2[df2.Item == 'Shirt'], on=['Item','Color', 'Price')
```

This will produce an output only when all columns in both dataframes match for Item='Shirt' and corresponding columns are also equal.

Let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Filter after `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2,on='Item').loc[lambda x : x.Item=='Shirt']
Out[89]: 
   Row_x   Item Color_x Price_x  Row_y Color_y Price_y
0      1  Shirt     Red     $30      4     Red     $30
```